# Prevent Cascade delete when the client is deleted

Tags: entity-framework-core, cascade

I'm having following configurations and relationships. i.e. when a Meal is deleted, relevant MealSubMeals should get deleted but not SubMeal. This is working as expected with following configuration. However, I don't want any MealSubMeals get deleted when a SubMeal is deleted. Instead, EF should throw an error when attempted to delete a SubMeal while MealSubMeals exist.

How do I achieve above? I probably don't want any cyclic relationships within my db.

Thanks!

```
public class Meal
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? MealName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<MealSubMeal>? MealSubMeals { get; set; }
}

public class MealSubMeal
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int MealId { get; set; }
    public Meal? Meal { get; set; }
    public bool Optional { get; set; }
    public decimal SubMealPrice { get; set; }
    public int SubMealId { get; set; }
    public SubMeal? SubMeal { get; set; }
}

public class SubMeal
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? SubMealName { get; set; }
    public string? SubMealDescription { get; set; }
}

public class MealConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Meal>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Meal> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(t => t.MealName).HasMaxLength(40).IsRequired();
        builder.HasIndex(t => t.MealName).IsUnique();
        builder.Property(t => t.Price).HasPrecision(10, 2).IsRequired();
    }
}

public class MealSubMealConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<MealSubMeal>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<MealSubMeal> builder)
    {
        builder.HasOne(t => t.Meal).WithMany(t => t.MealSubMeals).HasForeignKey(t => t.MealId).IsRequired();
        builder.HasOne(t => t.SubMeal).WithMany().HasForeignKey(t => t.SubMealId).IsRequired();
        builder.HasIndex(t => new { t.MealId, t.SubMealId }).IsUnique();
        builder.Property(t => t.SubMealPrice).HasPrecision(10, 2).IsRequired();
    }
}

public class SubMealConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<SubMeal>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<SubMeal> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(t => t.SubMealName).HasMaxLength(40).IsRequired();
        builder.HasIndex(t => t.SubMealName).IsUnique();
        builder.Property(t => t.SubMealDescription).HasMaxLength(200);
    }
}
```

Comment: So essentially you are asking for relationship with cascade delete off. What's the problem, sounds pretty standard `.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)` on the corresponding relationship configuration.

Comment: Isn't it going to restrict my first scenario as well? `builder.HasOne(t => t.SubMeal).WithMany().HasForeignKey(t => t.SubMealId).IsRequired().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)` i.e. deleting meals should delete mealsubmeals automatically.

Comment: It depends of your requirements. If as you wrote *"i.e. when a Meal is deleted, relevant MealSubMeals should get deleted"*, then no, you should leave that relationship with `DeleteBehavior.Cascade`, which is the default for *required* relationships. And no, these two relationships are independent, and cascade behavior of the one does not affect the cascade behavior of the other.

Comment: so, does it mean that all I need is `DeleteBehavior.Restrict` since relationships are independent here? i.e. deleting meals do delete MealSubMeals automatically and deleting SubMeals result in an error while MealSubMeals exists? If yes, I'm happy to accept it as the answer. Thanks!